# why the assertion is not used in deployment

Tags: java, assertions

Why the assertion is not usually used in deployment ?
I studied that asserting the public method arguments is inappropriate..but asserting private method arguments is appropriate in deployment..why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assertions are not enabled by default, you have to pass the `-ea` parameter to the JVM to enable them. So in many cases, it may be a simple omission in deployment. Other reasons may be performance (I have no evidence that asserts would noticeably slow down execution though), or proper error handling, i.e. it may be deemed inappropriate for the production system to throw `AssertionError`s live.

Asserting private method arguments is appropriate because you are supposed to be in full control over the arguments passed to them. Public methods OTOH are called from the outside world, so you may have no control over the concrete arguments passed, thus it is better to do explicit argument checks and handle invalid arguments appropriately (e.g. by throwing a suitable runtime exception such as `IllegalArgumentException`), or for null references, let the JVM throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Assertions are disabled by default, as the overhead make them only acceptable for development environments, as they're really helpful in finding bugs. In all your public methods you should check the input anyway, without relying on the assertions being enabled (the -ea JVM option), so that's why there they are (or should be) useless.

For your private methods, on the other hand, you have full control of all the method calls so you can make sure you provide the right arguments, but it's still good to assert that inside just to be able to detect any possible bugs as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

According to the seminal book, the pragmatic programmer, assertions are turned off by default because compiler writers and such have spread the idea that the performance overhead is unacceptable, and they only matter when debugging your code.

In fact, it's suggested that you leave assertions on because your testing might not find all bugs and because, when shipped, the chaos monkey can strike at any time. Assertions should only be turned off if you encounter are performance issues.

And it's also suggested that you should write own version of assert, that doesn't necessarily call exit when it fails.